# Firebase Database -Restrict value update to only once per user

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am using Firebase Realtime databse in an android app ,
the app contains articles and I want to add the Number of views to the articles through all the app users .

The database contains a child (ViewsCount) its value (is a number)
I need that value to be updated (incremented by 1) every time an article is viewed by a new user (Concept similar to YouTube video views)

The user have to be authenticated anonymously to update the value, but should not be able to do it more than once.

I got the logic integrated into the app to do just that and works great.
But what I am afraid of is if someone tries to connect to the database outside of my app (using their own code) and keeps incrementing the value.

My current security rules are:

```
"ViewsCount"
{
  ".write": "newData.exists() && auth!==null",
  ".validate" "newData.val()===data.val()+1"
}
"users": { 
  "$user_id": { 
    ".write": "auth.uid===$user_id", 
    ".read": "auth.uid===$user_id ",
  }
}
```

is there a way to restrict the update of a that value to only once per user via security rules ?.
Error :

Update : 
[screenshot from Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmSJD.png)
[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aO4Jf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the security rules that worked in case any one else have the same issue:

```
{"rules": {
"views": { 
  ".write": "auth != null",
".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['ViewsCount', 'viewedBy'])",

"ViewsCount": {
".read": "auth != null",
".validate":"data.parent().child('viewedBy').child(auth.uid).exists()== false"
},

"viewedBy": { 
"$user_id": { 
".validate": " auth.uid===$user_id && !data.exists() && newData.exists() &&
  newData.parent().parent().child('ViewsCount').val() === 
data.parent().parent().child('ViewsCount').val()+1
&& newData.val()===true"}},

     },
```

Answer (score 2):

There sure is, but you'll have to do some extra work. The first thing is to track in the database who has already viewed each article. For example keep a list of their UIDs, like this:

```
viewedBy: {
  uidOfKarim: true,
  uidOfPuf: true
}
```

Now when somebody views an article, they write their UID to `viewedBy`, and at the same time increment the view count for that article. In code that can be as simple as:

```
DatabaseReference countRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ViewsCount");
countRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    String uid = FirebaseAuthentication.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    Long newCount = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class) + 1;
    Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    updates.put("viewedBy/"+uid, true);
    updates.put("ViewsCount", newCount);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    throw databaseError.toException();
  }
}
```

So this code send the UID of the user *and* the new view count to the database. Now we update the security to only accept the write operation if the UID hasn't been stored yet and if the count is incremented by 1:

```
"viewedBy": { 
  "$user_id": { 
    ".validate": "
      auth.uid===$user_id && !data.exists() && newData.exists() &&
      newData.parent().parent().child('ViewsCount').val() === data.parent().parent().child('ViewsCount').val()+1
    "
  }
},
```

The syntax is a bit long, since it checks both the `ViewsCount` and the `ViewedBy` data. The write only succeeds if it increments by 1 and is from a user who hasn't been counted yet. If they have been counted before, or don't increment by 1, the write is rejected.

There is one edge case here: if multiple users view at almost the same time, one of their writes may be rejected, because they didn't actually increment the value:

```
user1       user2                   database
  |           |                        |
read_count ------------------->        |
  |           |                        |
  |        read_count -------->        |
  |           |                        |
  |        <------------------- 2      |
  |           |                        |
  |           |   <------------ 2      |
  |           |                        |
set_count 3 ------------------->       |
  |           |                        |
  |        set_count -------->         |
  |           |                        |
  |        <------------------- ok     |
  |           |                        |
  |           |   <------------ ACCESS |
  |           |                 DENIED |
  |           |                        |
```

In this case you should retry the update operation, reading the new value and determining the correct count based on that. This is actually how Firebase transactions work behind the scenes. Alternatively, you can first read from `viewedBy` to see if the current user has already been counted, before trying to count them. But either way: with these rules, each user can only count once.

---

**Update**: this is how I tested these rules in the simulator:

[image: Firebase Realtime Database rules simulator]

And this is the JSON I tested with:

```
"52469568": {
  "ViewsCount": 10,
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem here and what I worry about is if someone else with bad intentions writes a different code where he increment as many times as he want the viewsCount value without adding his UID to the node "viewdBy".  all he needs is to decompile the app, extract the json file , and write his own code with the same package name.

Comment: I think what I am asking is if it's possible to force adding The Viewer UID to the viewdBy Node after the ViewsCount was incremented . and to do so via Security Rules since those are accessed and could be changed by only me.

Comment: The above rules makes it impossible to increment without writing your UID to `viewedBy`, which each user can only do once according to the same rules. Give it a try, and let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: I will Thank you.

Comment: ".value":  returns an error ( Error saving rules - Line 23: Expected '{'. )   did you mean ".validate" ?

Comment: Woops, that should indeed be `.validate`. Good error message. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work the above code make the app crashes and returns this error (Firebase Database error: Permission denied
                      at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError.toException(Unknown Source) .....  I also tried via the simulator and it didn't work neither. I updated  the question and added a screenshot from the simulator and the database structure to the bottom of the post ... Can you please have a look at it ?

Comment: In the simulator you're missing a `.write` rule that allows writing on `/`. The simplest way to test this in your simulator is to put `".write": "auth != null"` on the root. I also added a screenshot of my simulator, showing the rules I used to test.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Frank van Puffelen , Your code helped but I had to add it to work.